# Passing Repeater Container.ItemIndex to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, parameters, repeater

In C# Asp.Net I need to pass my repeater occurrence index into a Javascript function when `OnClientClick` is depressed from an ASP button. Here is my code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGetNewQuote" 
            Text="Get New Quote" 
            class="pcbutton" 
            runat="server" 
            OnCommand="GetNewQuote" 
            CommandArgument ='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'  
            OnClientClick="return getNewQuote(<%# Container.ItemIndex %>) />
```

If I hard code ....OnClientClick="return getNewQuote(0)"> it works and the JS gets invoked, but as soon as I put the # Container.ItemIndex # in there the JS gets overlooked and it just posts back to the code behind...

Passing the `Container.ItemIndex` into JS Functions works every where else on the page except this `OnClientClick` ?

does anyone know why this is and what I can do to get around it?

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
OnClientClick='<%# "return getNewQuote(" + Container.ItemIndex + ")" %>'
```

Instead of

```
OnClientClick="return getNewQuote(<%# Container.ItemIndex %>)
```

Comment: @Adam: Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it solved your problem. Spread the love :)

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use in vb.net

OnClientClick='<%# "return getNewQuote(" & Container.ItemIndex & ")" %>'

otherwise it will give exception string is not in correct format