# accessing usercontrol properties from codebehind

Tags: asp.net

I have created a basic User Control with three drop down (Year,Month,Date) that exposes properties that 
I wish to set from my code-behind page. This works fine

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="DateControl.ascx.vb"  ClassName="DateControl"
    Inherits="DateControl" %>

<%--<asp:ScriptManager ID="dd" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>--%>
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDay" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLActual_OnChange" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLActual_OnChange" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLActual_OnChange" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem started when i placed this usercontorl in repeater and try to access from codebehind on every item change by creating
method

```
<uc3:DateControl ID="txtDate" runat="server" Visible="false" OnChange="txtDate_PostBack" />



Protected Sub txtDate_PostBack(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim btndetails As DateControl = TryCast(sender, DateControl)
    Dim ltrIsFormulaApplied As Literal = DirectCast(btndetails.FindControl("ltrIsFormulaApplied"), Literal)
End If
```

btndetails is showing nothing, i am not able to access values of other control, any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: Have you used the debugger? What type is sender? I also dont understand what you mean with _"on every item change"_. `RepeaterItem` or your custom control? Is this related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905959/accessing-repeater-item-controls-in-onchange-javascript?

Comment: Sender is {System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList}, As i am using this as date control, on every day,month and year change i am calling method on every repeater item.

Comment: Well, then this has never worked because a `DropDownList` <> `DateControl`. Where beneath this dropdown is the `ltrIsFormulaApplied` control you want to find? And where is the `txtDate`-control in the repeater?

Comment: <uc3:DateControl ID="txtDate" runat="server" Visible="false" OnChange="txtDate_PostBack" />, this is txtDate code, which is placed in <ItemTemplate>.